# Autocomplete/suggestion in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a database in Access, and I want to create a Textbox like this:

[image]

The suggestions come from the Database itself. It's for search for an item which are already in the Database.
How can I do that?

Comment: Use combobox with sql query in row source to populate the unique data.

Comment: Combobox RowSource: `SELECT DISTINCT [fieldname] FROM [tablename] ORDER BY [fieldname];`

Answer (score 0):

Create a combo box and in the property sheet, go under the data tab and set "Row Source Type" to Table/Query.

Set the "Row Source" to: SELECT [field] FROM [Table];

You should be able to search and it will autocomplete but you will need to click the dropdown arrow too see the suggestions.